# Controller not getting response from service when put in a function

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular and am stuck on an issue. I have created a controller which calls a service and the data is populating the screen. However, I am trying to execute functions after the first function has been called using .then and I am not receiving any data as if it doesn't exist. Why is my console statement empty?

```
app.service('UserOperations',function($http, $q){
    $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;

    this.getStores = function(user_id){
        var userStores;
        var stores = [];
        $http.get("http://localhost/shoploot_api/api/get-user-stores?user_id=" + user_id + "&&action=get_user_stores")
        .then(function (res) {
            userStores = res.data;
            angular.forEach(userStores, function(value, key){
                $http.get("http://localhost/shoploot_api/api/get-store?store_id=" + value.store_id + "&&action=get_store")
                .then(function (store) {
                    $http.get("http://localhost/shoploot_api/api/get-points?store_id=" + value.store_id + "&&user_id=" + user_id)
                    .then(function (points) {
                        if(points.data[0]['points']){
                            store.data[0]['points'] = points.data[0]['points'];
                        }else{
                            store.data[0]['points'] = 0;
                        }
                        store.data[0]['newMessage'] = 'hello';
                        stores.push(angular.merge(userStores[key],store.data[0]));
                    });
                }); 
            });
        });
        return stores;
    };

    this.getMessages = function(user_id,store_id){
        return 'working';
    }
});

app.controller('userStoresCtrl', function($scope, $q, UserOperations){
    var getStores = function(user_id){
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $scope.stores = UserOperations.getStores(user_id);
        defer.resolve($scope.stores);
        return defer.promise;
    }

    getStores(1).then(function(){
        console.log($scope.stores);
    });

    //$scope.stores = stores
});
```

Comment: Your `console.log` statement is being run before your `$http` promises have been resolved

Comment: What would I change to run them after? I've been trying at this for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below, you should always use promises whenever you make ajax calls.  That way, you make sure to resolve all requests.

```
app.service('UserOperations', function ($http, $q) {
    $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;

    this.getStores = function (user_id) {
        var userStores;
        var stores = [];
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get("http://localhost/shoploot_api/api/get-user-stores?user_id=" + user_id + "&&action=get_user_stores")
                .then(function (res) {
                    userStores = res.data;
                    angular.forEach(userStores, function (value, key) {
                        $http.get("http://localhost/shoploot_api/api/get-store?store_id=" + value.store_id + "&&action=get_store")
                                .then(function (store) {
                                    $http.get("http://localhost/shoploot_api/api/get-points?store_id=" + value.store_id + "&&user_id=" + user_id)
                                            .then(function (points) {
                                                if (points.data[0]['points']) {
                                                    store.data[0]['points'] = points.data[0]['points'];
                                                } else {
                                                    store.data[0]['points'] = 0;
                                                }
                                                store.data[0]['newMessage'] = 'hello';
                                                stores.push(angular.merge(userStores[key], store.data[0]));
                                                deferred.resolve(stores);
                                            });
                                });
                    });
                });
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    this.getMessages = function (user_id, store_id) {
        return 'working';
    }
});

app.controller('userStoresCtrl', function ($scope, $q, UserOperations) {
    UserOperations.getStores(user_id)
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
});
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks for the help. I see now I was using my defer in the completely wrong area. Thanks for giving me a better understanding of how to use them.